# How to remove white blank screen of splash from the ionic2 application?

Tags: ionic-framework, screen, splash-screen

I am trying to remove default splash screen from ionic 2 application, and for that I used the property `<preference name="SplashScreen" value="none" />` and the command `cordova plugin -rm cordova-plugin-splashscreen`, although that combination removed the splash but not completely, and I am still getting a blank white screen while launching the application.

How do I get rid of from the blank white screen?

Answer (score 1):

Config.xml

```
<preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashReloadOnOrientationChange" value="true" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

add these above lines

And in app.component.ts:

```
if (this.splashScreen) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.splashScreen.hide();
                }, 100);
            }
```

also build the app using command

```
ionic cordova build andorid --prod
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it on the second line of your main.ts:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
```

Then, before `...bootstrapModule...` in your main.ts add this line:

```
enableProdMode();
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: white screen still coming for 3-4 seconds. not solved

Comment: Are you launching app on device or emulator (which command)? You can build app using that: ionic cordova build android  --prod